# AngularJs update function with <select> <option> is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I am having very difficult time with AngularJS. I trying to convert some of my work with pure html to angularjs. My update function is not working on AngularjS

This working code with pure html: Whenever I make selection from dropdown it will update just fine.

```
 <div id="year" class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="selection" data-selection="Year">Select Year</span><span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">

        <li class="dropdown-submenu year">
          <a tabindex="-1" href="#" >2011</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu year">
          <a tabindex="-1" href="#" >2012</a>
        </li>

d3.selectAll('.dropdown-submenu.year > a').on("click", function(d) {
year = this.text;
chartsUpdate();
```

});

Here trying to achieve same thing with AngularJS:

```
    Year:
<select  class="YearSelector">
    <option  ng-repeat="year in chart_data |  unique: 'FiscalYear' | orderBy:'FiscalYear'" >
        {{ year.FiscalYear }}</option>
</select>

d3.selectAll('.YearSelectors').on("click", function (d) {
        FiscalYear = this.text;
        chartsUpdate();
    });
```

Update, Here us my chartsUpdate() function:

```
function chartsUpdate() {
        myChart.data = getData(data, FiscalYear, Quarter);
        myChart.draw(500);
    }
```

I have tried multiple ways to but none work, I feel like I am doing something really basic wrong. I am still newbie with both html and angularjs. 
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Comment: you should use ng-change on you select to call chartsUpdate... you should alos consider ngoptions instead of ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would need to see your controller, but theoretically I would suggest.

```
<select  class="YearSelector" ng-change="chartsUpdate()">
    <option  ng-repeat="year in chart_data |  unique: 'FiscalYear' | orderBy:'FiscalYear'" >
        {{ year.FiscalYear }}</option>
</select>
```

But as you learn angular, you should use ng-options with your select.

Comment: I don't have have controller for `chartsUpdate()` its pure javascript. I have edited my question with my functions. ng-change didn't work at the moment.

Comment: ok.. can I see your controller, and are you just a third party library for charting?

Comment: Here is some part of my code I hope it will help. I am using d3.js and dimple.js for charts. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23270529/ and thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: I am not sure where mychart is, or how it works, but your chartUpdate is in the controller. What happens if you make it accessible to the scope?  something like $scope.chartsUpdate = function chartsUpdate() {
            myChart.data = getData(data, FiscalYear, Quarter);
            myChart.draw(500);
        }

Comment: Didn't worked, but I have two error showing on console. 1)  Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from app 2) No controller: ngModel  <select class="YearSelector ng-scope" ng-change="updateChart">

Comment: I think we need to isolate our problems. Initially this was about updating a function with a select, but it's morphed it other things. Let break it down, into what appears to be three questions. The first question (and the original) should be how to call a function with ngselect. Can you start a plunkr with that isolated code (and I walk you through it)? No 3rd partly libraries, and we have to controllers. After that, we can step into 3rd parties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124821/discussion-between-mahmut-kilic-and-defaultcheckbox).

Comment: sorry I missed this. I will come back to it start the chat.

Answer (score 2):

Use **ng-change** and **ng-options**

```
<select class="YearSelector"
        ng-change="chartsUpdate()"
        ng-options="year.FiscalYear for year in chart_data |  unique: 'FiscalYear' | orderBy:'FiscalYear'">
</select>
```

Comment: Adding `ng-change="chartsUpdate()"` didn't worked. I edit my question with my functions. Also, I tried ng-options before didn't. I copy & paste your and it didn't worked again. It might because of the way is my data, not quite sure